# InputStream is null in IntelliJ but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ. But I can't start my project with IntelliJ. I have no problems with Eclipse. Is it a configuration error?

```
        String path = "/fxml/scene.fxml";
    InputStream fxmlStream = AppController.getInstance().getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    loader.setLocation(AppController.getInstance().getClass().getResource(path));
    loader.setController(AppController.getInstance());
    Parent pane = (Parent) loader.load(fxmlStream); // this is line 30
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
```

Stacktrace:

```
    Aug 12, 2017 11:31:35 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Exception in Application start method
Exception in Application stop method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: inputStream is null.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2455)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at app.VLCPlayerLauncher.start(VLCPlayerLauncher.java:30) // this is my program
    ...

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Debugger:
[image: IntelliJ Debugger]

What's wrong? Thanks. :)

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you determined where the null is coming from?

Comment: It comes from line 30. I commented it in my code. InputStream is null. But the location is correct.

Comment: Can you post the full buggy function ?

Comment: @user3646958 I mean have you checked where the null is coming from in the library code? You can set an Exception breakpoint in the debugger which will halt the code when the error happens, then you can look at the state of the code when and where the error happened.

Comment: Here you can see the file in my repository: https://bitbucket.org/alibranic/vpfx/src/bce980c47e71f75b5dcb020f2550e2e6b538b415/src/main/java/app/VLCPlayerLauncher.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: works fine for me in intellij.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen the project has it, but OP probably screwed it on hit PC and it is not marked as resource.

Comment: @Meo: How did you import my project? I tried it so many times as an existing maven project.

Comment: Open... | vpfx\pom.xml | Open as project | done.

Comment: As @Meo said, you can try go to project structure in intellij => right click on resources folder => use as resource. To mark your resources folder as resource in project

Comment: Well, I reproduced it, after importing as maven project- it even had the resource folder. Rebuild fixed it.

Comment: @Meo: I tried it again like you, but same error.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen: It is already a resources folder.

Comment: I have JDK 8_144.

Comment: do you have it like that?  http://imgur.com/a/1SzVE and how are you running it?

Comment: @Meo: No, fxml is missing after building: http://imgur.com/a/Hs44U

Comment: It works, if I copy the missing files into target/classes ... but not automatically?

Comment: @Meo: Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

to pom.xml.